# query a manytomany realted field

Tags: django

I have a model like the following:

GRN Model:

```
class GrnItems(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)


class Grn(models.Model):

    reference_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    inward_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(GrnItems)
```

How can I query the `GrnItems` to get `item_quantity` which has product = 5 and connected to grn = 103?

Comment: what do you mean has product = 5 ! wich field is product in your models ?

Comment: I am sorry  should have used `item`     item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
GrnItems.objects.filter(item_id=5, grn__pk=103)
```

Here the `grn` will query the `ManyToManyField` in reverse.

Comment: Just curious, the model name is `Grn` so why does Grn does not work in the query instead of grn?

Comment: @RahulSharma: because the `related_query_name` of a `ManyToManyField` (and `ForeignKey`) is, unless specified the name of the class in lowercase.